# Encrypting a JAR where source protection is a priority

Tags: java, encryption, jar, aes

I have a dilemma. Basically, I've given a group of people I'm friends with a program that utilizes source code that I don't want anyone outside the group knowing of. We all know Java is absolutely horrible at doing any level of obfuscation, as most obfuscation tools only rename objects, scramble code, etc. I've used such tools, but to be honest I'd like to go as far as possible with the security of the program.

Since the application requires a username, password, and other identifiers to log in to the server it uses, I was beginning to wonder if a unique AES key could be generated for the user to secure the JAR.

Basically, upon running a launcher of sorts to log in, the launcher app may request an AES key from the server, and use it to decrypt a secured JAR it's downloaded from the server already. The key would be completely unique to each user, which would mean the server would have to encrypt the JAR differently for each user.

Now, I know how crazy this sounds. But since this is such a low-level thing, I need to know if there is a way you can somehow both decrypt and run a JAR from any type of stream. Or, if that isn't possible, would it be reasonable to decrypt the file, run it, then re-encrypt it?

Comment: You don't have to put the source code in the JAR...

Comment: You cannot encrypt the bootstrap code since the client has to execute it. So an attacker could find out what it does and do the same to your encrypted jar. A bit more effort but not that difficult after all. Of course the attacker must be a legitimate user to do this.

Comment: *"Or, if that isn't possible, would it be reasonable to decrypt the file, run it, then re-encrypt it?"*  The only thing which would keep intrinsically valuable byte codes from the eyes of potential thieves is to not distribute it.  Hide it behind a web interface on a secure server if you can.  But you might be surprised how many people could still make code that does what yours does, just from seeing the result on screen (unless it uses a truly non-intuitive algorithm, which is unlikely).

Comment: Unless this is a mental exercise you will find this an exercise in futility. Given the amount of work you will need to do, the 'protection' is ultimately useless when an attacker can 'play' your byte codes and infer the logic from them.

Comment: better yet, if the the byte code is running on the user's machine, you have lost.  all they need to do is copy the unencrypted byte code to a new file and all your obfuscation work is for nothing.  this is DRM, DRM in all current forms is a failure.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can decrypt and run Java bytecode on the fly - bytecode manipulation libraries such as ASM even go as far as *creating* new classes dynamically.

But, quite honestly, if something actually runs on a computer then its code is definitely going to be available to anyone with the knowledge. Java, especially, is even more convenient since it allows far better access to the bytecode of a class that is loaded by the JVM than any natively compiled language.

You *could* theoretically take your obfuscation a bit further by using JNA/JNI and a native shared library or two. But, in the hands of a determined attacker no measure will protect your code completely - it would just take more time for them to figure out how your algorithms work. And if you are concerned about piracy, well, we are in the era of virtualization; you can actually clone whole computer systems from top to bottom with a couple of key presses - you figure out the rest...

The only potentially viable solution would be to offer your software as a service, with all the issues entailed by that approach - and you would *still* not have absolute security.

If you are that concerned about protecting your intellectual property, then get a lawyer and consider publishing your algorithms in some form - obscurity will only go so far. It will not stop someone from doing black-box analysis on your system and quite often just knowing that something is *possible* is enough.

*Please* stop trying to find technical solutions to a problem that is so obviously not of a technical nature...

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be to keep the server information outside of the jar entirely. Use a parameter or configuration file to point to where to get that information. Then the jar file has no secrets in it. Only the server where the code runs has that information. You can then do things like make the configuration file readable only by the user that can run the code in the jar.